# Loading and saving Mat file in a nested loop in Matlab

Tags: matlab, nested-loops

I want to load and save inside a nested loop in Matlab using "increasing" names, e.g.

```
for j=1:J
   for m=1:M
      load Bmj.mat
      ... A=...
      save A as Amj.mat
   end
end
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`sprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) to format strings

```
for ii=1:J
    for m=1:M
        suffix = sprintf( '%d%d.mat', ii, m );
        load( ['B', suffix] );
        % process...
        save( ['A', suffix], 'A' );
    end
end
```

PS,
It is best not to [use `i` as a variable name in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14790740/1714410).

Comment: I know it works but personally I don't usually see `,` for `horizcat`. +1 anyways

Answer (score 1):

What about `save(strcat('A',num2str(m),num2str(j),'.mat'),A)`?

I used [strcat](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcat.html) and [num2str](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html) to create a filename.